# Custom upload file scrolls to top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found a custom upload file code which is perfect for my need.

**Problem:**
When I click on the choose file button the page scrolls to top of the page as the popup to file explore opens.

**Result:**
Here I want the page should not scroll to top on open of file explore popup.

I am adding the complete structure and a codepen link below.

**Code:**

```css
label.file-label input[type="file"] {
    position:absolute;
    top: -1000px;
}

/***** Example custom styling *****/
.file-label {
    border: 1px solid #7A7A7A;
    /* border-radius: 4px; */
    padding: 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* .file-label:hover {
    background: #CCC;
} */
.file-label:active {
    background: #CCF;
}
.file-label :invalid + span {
    color: #000;
}
/* .file-label :valid + span {
    color: #4A4;
} */
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <label class="file-label">
        <input type="file" name="myFile" class="file-upload-ctrl" required/>
        <span>Choose File</span>
    </label>
    <span class="file-selected">No file chosen</span>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

**Codepen:**
[Custom popup](https://codepen.io/irfanshaikh/pen/ExjGYMz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed your

```
label.file-label input[type="file"] {
    position:absolute;
    top: -1000px;
}
```

To

```
label.file-label input[type="file"] {
     display: none;
}
```

As `top: -1000px` is causing the error

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/netumc1g/